# How to get middle indexOf if there are three identical strings?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to get the `indexOf` the middle string but if I use `indexOf` it returns only the first one, and if I use `lastIndexOf` it returns the last one.

So, I am trying to get the item in the middle.

Is it possible with `indexOf` in JavaScript?

```
var items = ['One', 'One', 'One'];
console.log(items.indexOf('One')); // returns 0 
console.log(items.lastIndexOf('One')); // returns 2
```

Comment: If the number of items is even, which one do you want?

Answer (score 1):

indexOf will find the first instance of the item you're looking for, so 0 is the first one. If you use the second argument, you can start from a different index.

If you want to get the next occurrence you may start from the next index, 
for ex. `items.indexOf('One', 1)`

You may want loop through your items if you want to find subsequent items

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

EDIT:
Now if what you want is to get the actual middle item you may want to do something like:
`var middleItem = Math.floor(items.length / 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Get all the occurence of `one` in the array and then get the middle syntax.

```js
const res = ['One', 'Two', 'One', 'One'].reduce(function(acc, e, i) {
    if (e === 'One')
        acc.push(i);
    return acc;
}, []);
const mid = res[Math.floor(res.length/2)];
console.log(mid);
```

Comment: You could have used `array#filter` instead of `array#reduce`.

Comment: @HassanImam It won't be the same thing because here, the resulting array is an array of indexes.

Comment: Didn't notice the you are storing index.